# Android SQLite Database cannot downgrade

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Thank you in advance for answering to my question. I've been struggling with this(these)problem(s) for the last 2 days and I am literally going crazy. Let me tell you my story,
I am using List with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` along with information extracted from a SQLite Database. I am new to Android(2weeks) and for that matter to Java. I was pleased to realise that I have actually achieved everything I wanted to, with my little app.

Yesterday, it occured to me that the architecture of my Database Table was not eficiently structured. So I tried to alter it.

Following one of the tips found here on SO, I've inserted the ALTER query in the onUpgrade method, and set the Dabase version to a higher number, in order to trigger the method. From database version 1, i made it 2 and then 3. I kept receiving the same mistake: COLUMN XXX not found in the TABLE XXX. So the ALTER query was clearly not triggered.

I set the version back to 1, and then the error changed: CANNOT DOWNGRADE DATABASE. I have tried to delete manually the database. But because of the d* folder permissions, I couldn't access it. I tried following some tutorial to change the file permission from Windows Shell. USELESS. Meaning I wasn't able to change the permission.

Further, I have tried to delete the database with the command context.deleteDatabase(Databasename). Afterwards I've renamed the Java class file with the adapter and the SQLiteHelper extension class. I get THE SAME ERROR.

Over and over! Cannot downgrade database. What should I do?

Please! Maybe export all content to a clean new project? :O
This is my code of the blessed class!

```
public class VerbsAdapter{
//declare all the verb fields for the data columns

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_VERBNAME = "verbname";
public static final String KEY_FPERSSG = "firstperssg";
public static final String KEY_FPERSPL = "firstperpl";
public static final String KEY_SPERSSG = "secondperssg";
public static final String KEY_SPERSPL = "secondperspl";
public static final String KEY_TPERSSG = "thirdperssg";
public static final String KEY_TPERSPL = "thirdperspl";
public static final String TAG = "tag";

private static final String DB_NAME = "LearnGermanDB";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TableVerb";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE if not exists "+TABLE_NAME+ "(" + KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"+TAG+","+KEY_VERBNAME +
        ","+KEY_FPERSSG + "," +KEY_FPERSPL + "," + KEY_SPERSSG + "," + KEY_SPERSPL + "," + KEY_TPERSSG + "," + KEY_TPERSPL+ ");";

    //extend the SQLiteOpenHelper
    //implement onCreate and onUpgrade

    private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DataBaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE_QUERY);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_QUERY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public VerbsAdapter(Context context){
        this.mCtx = context;
    }


    public VerbsAdapter open(){
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }


   public void deleteDatabase(){
        mCtx.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        Log.w(TAG,"Database DELETED");
        Toast.makeText(mCtx,"Database deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public long createVerb(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5,String s6,String s7){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(TAG,"verb");
        initialValues.put(KEY_VERBNAME,s1);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FPERSSG,"ich "+s2);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FPERSPL,"wir "+s3);
        initialValues.put(KEY_SPERSSG,"du "+s4);
        initialValues.put(KEY_SPERSPL,"ihr "+s5);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TPERSSG,"er "+s6);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TPERSPL,"sie,Sie "+s7);

        return mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteAllVerbs() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;

    }

    public Cursor fetchAllVerbs(){
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_VERBNAME,
                KEY_FPERSSG,KEY_FPERSPL,KEY_SPERSSG,KEY_SPERSPL,KEY_TPERSSG,KEY_TPERSPL},null,null,null,null,null);
        if (mCursor!=null){
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    public void insertVerbs(){
        createVerb("machen = to make , conjugated with: HABEN","mache","machen","machst","macht","macht","machen");
        createVerb("tun = to do, conjugated with HABEN","tue","tun","tust","tut","tut","tun");
        createVerb("essen = to eat, conjugated with HABEN","esse","essen","isst","esst","isst","essen");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also changed the name of the database itself and the name of the table!

Comment: If you want to delete the database you can simply uninstall the app from your device. I also think that you can use `adb pull` to download the DB bypassing the permission flags, so I think that you can replace it too by using `adb push`

Comment: where is the alter query? Right now you keep executing always the same query independently of the db version. I guess you modified DATABASE_CREATE_QUERY manually at some stage after having an existing db. In any case, you should control the upgrades in code.